# do not implement two orders in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

in sql when submit those orders the first one just occurs
how can i impelment both of them ?
i want to got my longest name of song and shortest name of song on my list

```
SELECT name, LENGTH(name) FROM songs ORDER BY LENGTH(name),
name LIMIT 1;
SELECT name, LENGTH(name) FROM songs ORDER BY LENGTH(name) DESC,
name LIMIT 1;
```

my out put
Edit Copy Delete  BreakingTheHabit.mp3 20
just one row for the first one

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also explain how you are "submitting" the statements.

Comment: click go in phpmyadmin

Comment: In your current form it returns two result sets, which not all clients are capable of reading. You could use `UNION` to get only one with two rows, or create a single `SELECT` query with two subqueries to get one row with two colums.

Comment: @Alejandro  how may i do that in code

Comment: Although it probably makes little difference, technically, you want CHAR_LENGTH

Comment: Phpmyadmin shows multiple results one after another. Just scroll down and you'll find your second query.